# how to get a button in an Openlayers popup?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, openlayers

I am trying to put a button inside of an Openlayers popup.  While the button appears to display correctly with the following code, the function 'handlerFunc' does not execute when the button is clicked.  The segment of code I have posted is all within another function (so handlerFunc is actually a nested function).  I'm using JQuery for the button itself.  Any ideas on what might be going wrong? Thanks!

```
    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(presences, ll); 
        feature.popupClass = popupClass;
        feature.data.popupContentHTML = "<button id='popupButton'>Click me</button>";
        feature.data.overflow = (overflow) ? "auto" : "hidden";
        feature.data.icon = markerIcon;
    $('#popupButton').button();
    $('#popupButton').click(handlerFunc);


 function handlerFunc() {
    // do something
 }
```

Comment: so this doesn't work? `$('#popupButton').click(function(){alert("foo");});` Also, are you setting a high enough `z-index`?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely reason is that your button doesn't exist when you bind to a `click` event. `$('#popupButton')` returns `null`. Instead of using `$('#popupButton').click(handlerFunc);` try `$('#popupButton').live('click', handlerFunc);`. That means that we bind to an event not only when DOM is built, but when object appears.

Comment: Thank you. I found out that my problem was solved when I made the handler function global; for some reason, the local function was not in the correct scope.